# Excluir um registro em struct usando free()

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Estou criando um cadastro usando `struct`, onde devo ter um menu para incluir, mostrar e atender (excluir) os pacientes.

O problema está na função excluir que por minha falta de conhecimento não entendo qual seria a forma correta de realizar. Pensei em usar o `free()` mas por lidar diretamente com a memória não tenho certeza se funcionaria em todos os casos.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    char menu(){
        fflush (stdin);
        printf ("\n\t\t-----Menu-----");
        printf ("\n\t\t 1 Incluir Paciente");
        printf ("\n\t\t 2 Mostrar Pacientes");  
        printf ("\n\t\t 3 Atender Paciente");   
        printf ("\n\t\t 0 Sair");
        char op = getch();
        system ("cls");
        return op;
    }

    typedef struct paciente{
        char nome [20], matricula [6], senha[6], atendimento[50];
        struct paciente *prox;
    }pacienteat;

    pacienteat *ini, *aux;

    void inicio(){
        ini= NULL;
    }

    int estaVazia(){
        return (ini==NULL);
    }

    void inserir (){
        int senha=1;

        aux=(pacienteat*) malloc(sizeof(pacienteat));
        printf("\nInforme o numero do atendimento");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(aux->atendimento);

        printf ("\nInforme o nome do paciente: ");
        fflush (stdin);
        gets (aux->nome);

        printf ("\nInforme o numero da matricula: ");
        fflush (stdin);
        gets (aux->matricula);

        printf ("\nInforme a senha atendimento: ");
        fflush (stdin);
        gets (aux->senha);;

        aux->prox = ini;
        ini = aux;
    }

    void listar(){  
        for (aux = ini; aux != NULL; aux = aux->prox){
            printf("\nNome: %s - Matricula: %s - Atendimento: %s - Senha: %s", aux->nome, aux->matricula, aux->atendimento, aux->senha);
        }
    }

    void excluir(){
        int n_remover;
        listar();
        printf("Digite o numero de quem voce quer remover");
        scanf("%d",&n_remover);
        aux[n_remover] = aux[aux->atendimento-1]; 
        atendimento--; 
        aux = (pacienteat*) realloc(pacienteat,num*sizeof(pacienteat));
    }
    int main(){
        inicio();
        int x=0,nn;

        char op=menu();
        while(op != '0'){
            switch (op){
                case'1':
                    inserir();
                    break;
                case'2':
                    listar();
                    break;
                case'3':
                    excluir();
                    break;
            }
            op = menu();
        }
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Para um código de exercício isso está bom, mas saiba que em código real seria algo bem diferente disso. Algumas coisas neste código funcionam por coincidência, em certas situações não funcionará.

Como está usando uma lista ligada não tem porque realocar. Só deveria usar o `free()`. Tem que ser dado no endereço do elemento da lista. E aí o elemento anterior deve receber o endereço do elemento que era apontado no elemento que está sendo removido, que pode até ser 0.

O `aux[n_remover]` não faz sentido porque você não tem um *array*, nem mesmo através de um ponteiro estável e linear.

Não faço ideia o que seja `atendimento--`, a impressão que dá que escolheu algo aleatório e jogou no código.

Tenho medo desse `aux`, parece gambi da grossa e duvido que isso esteja funcionando a não ser em um teste muito ingênuo.

Quando vários erros fica até difícil achar uma solução, porque vai tendo que resolver todos até funcionar.

Comment: Entendi, o aux[n_remover] eu tentei adaptar de um código anterior porquê na realidade eu sou péssimo em C como já é notável, então não tenho muita noção. Toda a função excluir() eu só tentei adaptar de um outro exercício mas não funcionou. 

A respeito desse aux, é meio que padrão na sala de aula o uso dele então sempre usamos, foi uma forma do professor introduzir linguagens de programação(o que eu discordo totalmente já que essa é dificílima).

Cara essa atividade vale pontos e eu passei a semana toda tentando fazer esse negócio funcionar e não adianta! Me dê uma luz por favor

Comment: Pelo que tem na pergunta o que dá para ajudar é isto.